# Unable to change chunkSize in MongoDB

Tags: java, android, mongodb, parse-server

I have deployed a MongoDB which is the database of my Parse server. But I'm not able to upload files more than 700 kilobytes to parse server, with `parseFile.saveFileInBackground()` function in parse-android-SDK. The exception thrown by callback is `I/O Failure`, and the cause is timeout. I considered too many issues, and I figured out maybe changing the default chunk size that files are divided into them in MongoDB, works something out. I used `db.settings.save( { _id:"chunkSize", value: <size-in-magabyte> } )` in MongoDB shell. But I can not really feel any changes. After this command `chunkSize` field of entries stored under `files.fs` class in MongoDB, is still the same as before, 261120. What I actually want to do is change this 261120 to 358400. I want my files to be divided into chunks of size 358400 byte and not 261120. Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: The DB parameter `chunkSize` applies only for [sharded cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/modify-chunk-size-in-sharded-cluster/index.html), don't mix it with `chunkSize` field in the [files Collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/index.html#gridfs-collections)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit So if I shard my collections can I change the size of chunks which files are divided into?

Comment: No, these are two different parameters which just have the same name.

Comment: You mean it is not possible to achieve it?

Comment: To achieve what? Sort and simple: setting DB parameter "chunkSize" has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Please forget about what I've done. The files that I save to my mongodb are divided into 261120 byte chunks. I want them to be divided into 358400 byte chunks. Is it possible? And it should be done by a configuration in mongodb cause using Gridfs in client side is not an option

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change the mongodb chunk size from default value of 261120bytes chunks to 3000000 bytes chunks. I am using multer gridfs storage and below is the code I did to increase the chunk size:

```
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  db: connection,
  file: (req,file) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    const fileInfo = {
      filename: file.originalname,
      bucketName: "file_uploads",
      chunkSize: 3000000
    };
    resolve(fileInfo);
  });
  }
});
```